# AHK debugging: How to know current line number being executed

Tags: debugging, scripting, autohotkey

I have a AHK script which I need  to debug. I basically want to see which line number is being currently executed in the script (which piece of code).

Is there a way to do that? Or anything close to that for debugging? 
I am using this AHK script to automate some windows explorer related task. But sometimes it gets stuck in between and I have no idea where the script gets stuck. 
If I knew the current line number being executed, it would be great.
Using Msgbox after each line is not possible and very inefficient.

Could someone please help me with this?

Also, I am new to AHK scripting so I would be grateful if you could explain with a short example if possible.

Thanks
Sunny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list recent lines, you can show it programmatically by adding the command [ListLines](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ListLines.htm) to your code.

OR right-click the AutoHotkey icon, select `Open`, and select `Lines most recently executed` in the `View` menu.